# XML parsing with class will not find the values

Tags: python-3.x, xml, class, oop, elementtree

I will split a large XML to small branches and than parse only this parts.
I search modified timestamp "mod_time" tag which is avaliable in "contacts" tag, but my object function call, doesn't find the value. In some contacts is also some tags missing completly.

I tried `iterfind('tag_name')`, `iter()`, `findall('tag_name')`, but my program shows no result and I can't figure out for hours, where my failure is.

Here is my XML reduced to two elements:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding = "utf-8"?>
<phonebooks>
  <phonebook name="Telefonbuch">
   <contact>
      <category>0</category>
      <person>
        <realName>Dummy, Name, Street</realName>
      </person>
      <telephony nid="1">
        <number type="work" prio="1" id="0">012345678</number>
      </telephony>
      <services />
      <setup />
      <features doorphone="0" />
      <mod_time>1587477163</mod_time>
      <uniqueid>358</uniqueid>
    </contact>
    <contact>
      <category>0</category>
      <person>
        <realName>Foto Name</realName>
      </person>
      <telephony nid="1">
        <number type="home" prio="1" id="0">067856743</number>
      </telephony>
      <services />
      <setup />
      <features doorphone="0" />
      <mod_time>1547749691</mod_time>
      <uniqueid>68</uniqueid>
    </contact>
</phonebook>
</phonebooks>
```

and her what I have done so fare:

```
import timeit
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

class Phonebook:
    def __init__(self, xml_file, tag_node):
        """Split tree in contact branches """
        self.xml_file = xml_file
        self.tag_node = tag_node
        # For furter parsing
        contacts = []
        i = 0
        events =('start','end','start-ns','end-ns')
        for event, elem in ET.iterparse(self.xml_file, events=events):
            if event == 'end' and elem.tag == self.tag_node[0]:
                #print(elem.tag)
                contacts.append(elem)
                par = Contact(elem, i)
                par.parse_node(elem, i)
                i += 1
            elem.clear()
        print("Amount of contacts:", len(contacts))


class Contact:
    def __init__(self, branch, i):
        self.tree = branch
        #print(i, self.tree)
       
    def parse_node(self, branch, i):
        for node in branch.iterfind('.//mod_time'):
           print(node.text)               
         
def main():
    elem = Phonebook('new _dummy1.xml',['contact'])

    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    """ Input XML file definition """
    starttime=timeit.default_timer()
    main()
    print('Finished')
    print("Runtime:", timeit.default_timer()-starttime)
```

Output:
`Amount of contacts: 2  Finished  Runtime: 0.0006361000050674193`

Expected output:

1587477163
1547749691

Comment: In the meantime I wrote the branch from Phonbook to a xml file, this element contains all the tags and content of the partial tree. I think there must be a failure with the handshake of the data between this two objects.

Comment: @mzjn in the end I will parse each tag and attribute. The idea was to provide a list of tag names and call the class by them for each. With such a tag list, my code is flexibel to use, also for other xml files. I will import all this data into a SQLite db.

Comment: @mzib, I don't think so, because if I write "elem" to a text file after the call `par.parse_node(elem, i) ` the xml contains the whole content with all subelements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved now my issue with the handshake of the object data. I create now an instance of Contact which inherit the values from the parent class Phonbook, instead of call Contact from Phonbook Object. Very helpful was the python documentation about the

```
super()
```

function, which refers to this great [page](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/). I post my solution, because it's maybe interessting for others who run in similar issues.
**Thanks to all who tried to help!**

My changed code:

```
import psutil
import timeit

import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

class Phonebook:
    def __init__(self, file_path):
        """Split tree in contact branches """
        self.file_path = file_path
    
    def contacts_list(self, file_path):    
        contacts = []
        events =('start','end','start-ns','end-ns')
        for event, elem in ET.iterparse(self.file_path, events=events):
            if event == 'end' and elem.tag == 'contact':
                contact = elem
                contacts.append(contact)
        elem.clear()
        return contacts
        #print("Superclass:",contacts)
        
class Contact(Phonebook):
    def __init__(self, file_path):
        super().__init__(file_path)
               
    def search_node(self, contact, searched_tag):
        contact_template =['category','person', 'telephony', 'services', 'setup', 'features', 'mod_time', 'uniqueid' ]
        node_tag_list = []
        list_difference = []
        search_list = []
        for node in contact:
            if node.tag not in node_tag_list:
                node_tag_list.append(node.tag)
        for element in contact_template:
            if element not in node_tag_list:
                list_difference.append(element)
        
        for node in contact:
            if node.tag == searched_tag and node.tag not in list_difference:
                search_list.append(node.text)
                #print(node.text)
            else:
                if len(list_difference) != 0 and searched_tag in list_difference:
                    message = self.missed_tag(list_difference)
                    #print(message)
                    if message not in search_list:
                        search_list.append(message)                
        return  search_list
                        
    def missed_tag(self, list_difference):
        for m in list_difference:
            message = f'{m} - not assigned'
            return message
                    
         
def main():
    con = Contact('dummy.xml')
    contacts = con.contacts_list(('dummy.xml'))
    
    mod_time_list =[]
    for contact in contacts:
        mod_time = con.search_node(contact, 'mod_time')
        mod_time_list.append(mod_time)
    print(len(mod_time_list))
    print(mod_time_list)
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    """ Input XML file definition """
    starttime=timeit.default_timer()
    main()
    print('Finished')
    # Getting % usage of virtual_memory ( 3rd field)
    print('RAM memory % used:', psutil.virtual_memory()[2])
    # Getting usage of virtual_memory in GB ( 4th field)
    print('RAM Used (GB):', psutil.virtual_memory()[3]/1000000000)
    print("Runtime:", timeit.default_timer()-starttime)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Added reference to the python doc, what solves my trouble. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Code

```
import timeit
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

class Phonebook:
    def __init__(self, xml_file, selector):
        self.xml_file = xml_file
        self.selector = selector
        root = ET.parse(xml_file)
        contacts = root.findall(selector)  
        print("Amount of contacts:", len(contacts))
        for mod_time in contacts:
            print(mod_time.text)

def main():
    Phonebook('./_dummy1.xml','.//contact/mod_time')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    starttime=timeit.default_timer()
    main()
    print('Finished')
    print("Runtime:", timeit.default_timer()-starttime)
```

Output

```
$ python test.py
Amount of contacts: 2
1587477163
1547749691
Finished
Runtime: 0.0006627999973716214
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. This works for my small dummy, but doesn’t solve my problem. I have two concerns: 1.) I will not load the whole xml into memory, because I work the huge xml file size on a old Rasp pi. 2) If the searched tag is completely missing, it shows a wrong result.

Comment: @Paul-ET, #1 I did not test but it's memory size limit is [10MB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33828728/what-is-the-maximum-size-of-an-xml-file-when-using-pythons-lxml-etree), I think it cover most XML file. On fly method is slow and hard to debug  #2 the XPath selector is flexible to apply any hierarchy structure of [DOM tree](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html).

Comment: The 10MB limit seems irrelevant here. 1) It applies to libxml2 and lxml (not ElementTree in the standard library). 2) It does not refer to a complete XML document; it refers to the maximum size of a single text node.

Comment: @mzjn, thanks, OK not whole XML file limit. It is max node size.